# HLS stream playing only when first segment is in m3u8 list

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, hls

I am transcoding a live DVB-T2 HEVC stream to H264 using ffmpeg. I have decided to use the HLS (segmented) output format (because I want to play the stream in a web browser, e.g. on Android phone).

I successfully created the segmented output using the following ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel rpi -c:v hevc -i input.ts -c:v h264_v4l2m2m -c:a aac -b:v 1500k -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -num_capture_buffers 64 -hls_time 10 -start_number 0 -hls_list_size 5 -hls_flags delete_segments -f hls tv.m3u8
```

(In this example I am using an input.ts file, but normally I will use URL of the live stream)

I have created a simple HTML player based on https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/ (example HTML is on their page).

The video plays successfully in browser and it can play for hours without any problem. But it can play only if I start it with the first segment (tv0.ts) and if I don't reload the HTML page.

If I reload the HTML page in browser and the first segment (tv0.ts) is no longer in the playlist (as old segments get deleted), the stream starts to play as audio-only (see picture).

[image: player]

I was trying to find a solution for few days, but I am not an expert. I want to keep only last few segments (because it is a live stream). I tried several ffmpeg parameters (`-movflags faststart`, `-reset_timestamps 1`, `-g 50 -keyint_min 50`, `-flags +cgop`) with no luck, but maybe I used them incorrectly.

I have noticed that the tv0.ts is playable in a video player, but others play audio-only. Idk if this is expected, because as I said, the stream plays fine (both audio and video) for hours if started with tv0.ts.

I am clueless. Any help or ideas will be very appreciated, thank you!

I have shared all files (.ts, .m3u8, ffmpeg log) here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lwz9p229sxplxxh/AABb8_yYIIFw9Gy0-oq9iniRa?dl=0

**ffprobe tv0.ts:**

```
ffprobe version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1+rpt1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --cpu=arm1176jzf-s --arch=arm
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avutil      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avformat    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avdevice    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avfilter    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avresample  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  swscale     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  swresample  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  postproc    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'tv0.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:12.00, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 1347 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 30 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](cze): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
```

**ffprobe tv1.ts:** (shortened output)

```
ffprobe version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1+rpt1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --cpu=arm1176jzf-s --arch=arm
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[h264 @ 0x686160] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x686160] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x686160] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x686160] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x686160] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x686160] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x686160] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x686160] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x686160] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x686160] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x686160] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x686160] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x686160] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x686160] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x686160] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x686160] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x686160] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x686160] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x686160] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x686160] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x686160] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x686160] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x686160] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x686160] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x686160] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x686160] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x686160] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x686160] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x686160] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x686160] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x686160] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x686160] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
...
[h264 @ 0x686160] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x686160] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x686160] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[mpegts @ 0x681a00] decoding for stream 0 failed
[mpegts @ 0x681a00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'tv1.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:09.60, start: 13.400000, bitrate: 1459 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](cze): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, ltp, 132 kb/s
```

Comment: This is a very old post - but were you able to resolve this issue? I am seeing very similar issues with the h264_v4l2m2m encoder

Comment: Found this: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20820/h264-omx-and-non-existing-pps-0-referenced . The encoder is different, but uses the same magical broadcom magic under the hood. And it's broken.